# Unauthorized on access to WSS spsearch.asmx

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, wss

I am running an ASP.NET web application that connects to the WSS 3.0 search web service (spsearch.asmx).

The WSS site itself is configured for anonymous access: site search works with chrome, firefox and so on without the need of an authorization.

I also set anonymous rights for the spsearch.asmx, but I get an Unauthorized when trying to connect using the generated web service proxy. I tried a lot of settings (PreAuthenticate and so on). Nothing works. Is there a special configuration necessary, or doesn't work this web service with anonymous authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely you can't use any of the built in web services with anonymous access regardless of settings in SharePoint and IIS.

You could write your own web service that would proxy for the built in ones and access them using the IIS worker account or another 'site reader' account.

[The SharePoint Search Service and Anonymous Access](http://www.trinkit.co.nz/blog/archive/2009/04/09/the-sharepoint-search-service-and-anonymous-access.aspx)

[Writing Custom Web Services for SharePoint Products and Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583131%28office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Lists listService = new Lists();
            listService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("usr", "pass", "DOM");
            listService.Url = "http://server/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

change the list.asmx for search.asmx dir

List is the WebReference of the SharePoint 2010 web service